# CSS File Structure

Tags: css, naming-conventions, file-structure

Is there any best practices or very practical solutions to organizing mass amounts of css files.

Firstly, how should you use css within a page, should you have a external style sheet for each individual page, and a include css file for 'css reset' and all common elements. Say you have a included header how would you style it, would you have another external style sheet.

This just add up to mass amounts of style sheets, then secondly how to you organize them, do you have a folder for each external style sheet for each page?

Lastly, is there any standard naming conventions, for example if the file was an include would it be 'filename.inc.css' or if it was for a specific page would it be 'filename.pagename.css'

Comment: Uh....  Isn't the POINT of CSS that you don't need an individual style sheet for each page?  Unless you're programmatically generating the stylesheets (Which, well, leads to a whole different set of questions, but then you're outside the standard purveyance of stylesheets) each page having its own styling is pretty cumbersome.  Sure, there are naming conventions out there, but the most competent web designers I've worked with were happy with my hooks and created a comparatively small number of stylesheets for overall site design then embedded page-specific CSS in the pages themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I object to the premise of the question...somewhat. The fact you have so many CSS files speaks to unnecessary bloat. You are probably coupling your styles to a specific context rather than to *classes* of content. Check out [what they are doing at Yahoo](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/21/challenging-css-best-practices-atomic-approach/) for what I mean.

When your CSS is less-context specific, it becomes leaner. This then dramatically reduces the size of your files and mitigates your issue by curing the disease rather than treating the symptom.

So take the time to rethink your CSS to make sure it is only as big as it needs to be. Then organize your layout according just to whatever makes sense for you. After all, the layout of your CSS into multiple files is for your benefit only as a developer. The files will be minified and combined into a single file for the purposes of caching and performance.

And CSS files that are less likely to change because they have been designed for maximum immutability are ideal for caching.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://smacss.com/

> SMACSS (pronounced “smacks”) is more style guide than rigid framework.
>   ... SMACSS
>   is a way to examine your design process and as a way to fit those
>   rigid frameworks into a flexible thought process. It is an attempt to
>   document a consistent approach to site development when using CSS.

My advise is always use a preprocessor, it makes the modularity easier. And use SMACSS because is the best way to do CSS especially when dealing with large styles. Check bootstrap repo for an example https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less

Comment: SMACSS is awesome, but I don't remember it saying anything about file structure. That makes sense, though, since ideally, all of the css is combined.

Comment: http://smacss.com/book/categorizing

Comment: Oh right. He does briefly mention files there.

Comment: Even if SMACSS doesn't mention file structure a lot, but it's immediate, modules are single or multiple files .. user choose his modular structure

Comment: No debate here! It's a good contribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stylesheet for each page, then every page will have to download a new file. That's definitely not good. You want to take advantage of caching (this goes for anything on the web, not just css) so it would be better to have a little more overhead on a larger css file that only needs to be downloaded once for the whole site. This is a subjective question, however, so there could be and probably are cases where it could be better to split them up - maybe if there were two distinct parts of a site that both needed a massive amount of css.

Generally, having multiple css files is for development only and they should be combined for performance reasons. For example, if I had a `menu.css`, `header.css`, etc, those should be in one file when deployed. One example where multiple css files is more acceptable is when they are lazy-loaded by a plugin system like Content Management Systems use. Because the content is so dynamic and the plugins are not tightly coupled to the CMS, it doesn't make sense for all of the css to be combined. That would make it pretty difficult to add and remove plugins.

Oh! In addition to combining all of the css, minification is also great!

There are also libraries like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) that are useful in organizing code and cutting down on the amount you need to write.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to have one external style sheet for the entire website. If you can try to name your classes and id's uniquely where they need to be set apart so that there is no confusion between them all in your styling. This way you can maintain the entire site from one file.

If it is absolutely necessary for you to have different style sheets for each page then keep the majority of the styles you will need to render and load that are not page specific and occur on all of the pages to one main css file, then keep the remaining ones that are page specific to a minimum, this will keep your performance higher and save yourself a lot of headaches down the road.

The less technical debt you acquire the better.

Also if you do need multiple style sheets and there are page specific styles you will need that occur on several pages, I would recommend bundling and merging your style sheets to keep the downloads to a minimum and keep your performance higher.